# TSQL define group statuses based on group row statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, case

Hi any ideas how i can define group statuses based on group row statuses or what I should be googling?
In the below Group Status is what I'm after. Thanks

```
Group  Row Status  Group Status
A      Good        Good
B      Good        Neutral
B      Neutral     Neutral
B      Bad         Neutral
C      Bad         Bad
D      Good        Error
D      Bad         Error
D      Error       Error
```

There is an error in my table above, Good+Neutral+Bad=Bad and C should be Neutral=Neutral so this will cause some confusion with answers from @forpas and @Gordon Linoff
I have added another table below to better show cases/rules 
Any mix with an Error = Error 
Any mix of Good Neutral Bad = Bad 
Any distinct Status = that Status

```
Group   Row Status  Group Status
A       Good        Bad
A       Bad         Bad
A       Neutral     Bad
B       Good        Bad
B       Bad         Bad
C       Good        Bad
C       Neutral     Bad
D       Bad         Bad
D       Neutral     Bad
E       Good        Good
F       Bad         Bad
G       Neutral     Neutral
H       Error       Error
I       Good        Error
I       Bad         Error
I       Neutral     Error
I       Error       Error
J       Good        Error
J       Bad         Error
J       Error       Error
K       Good        Error
K       Neutral     Error
K       Error       Error
L       Bad         Error
L       Neutral     Error
L       Error       Error
M       Good        Error
M       Error       Error
N       Bad         Error
N       Error       Error
O       Neutral     Error
O       Error       Error
```

I was able to get result i wanted using @forpas method. I think this should cover all my cases.

```
with cte as (
  select
    [Group],
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) good,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Neutral' then 1 else 0 end) neutral,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end) bad,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) error
  from [Test].[dbo].[GroupStatus]
  group by [Group]
)
select 
  t.*,
  case 
    when c.error > 0 then 'Error'
    when c.good * c.neutral * c.bad > 0 then 'Bad'
    when c.good * c.neutral > 0 then 'Bad'
    when c.bad * c.neutral > 0 then 'Bad'
    when c.good * c.bad > 0 then 'Bad'
    when c.good > 0 then 'Good'
    when c.bad > 0 then 'Bad'
    when c.neutral > 0 then 'Neutral'
    else 'Error'
  end [Group Status] 
from [Test].[dbo].[GroupStatus] t inner join cte c
on c.[Group] = t.[Group]
```

Comment: Please explain the rules for the group statuses.  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** after the new sample data and clarifications.
You can solve the problem with conditional aggregation:

```
with cte as (
  select
    [Group],
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) good,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Neutral' then 1 else 0 end) neutral,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end) bad,
    sum(case [Row Status] when 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) error
  from tablename
  group by [Group]
)
select 
  t.*,
  case 
    when c.error > 0 then 'Error'
    when (c.bad > 0) or (c.good * c.neutral > 0) then 'Bad'
    when c.neutral > 0 then 'Neutral'
    when c.good > 0 then 'Good'
    else 'Error'
  end [Group Status]
from tablename t inner join cte c
on c.[Group] = t.[Group]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aab82e9fa528f2154223c0a75478b866).
Results:

```
> Group | Row Status | Group Status
> :---- | :--------- | :-----------
> A     | Good       | Bad         
> A     | Bad        | Bad         
> A     | Neutral    | Bad         
> B     | Good       | Bad         
> B     | Bad        | Bad         
> C     | Good       | Bad         
> C     | Neutral    | Bad         
> D     | Bad        | Bad         
> D     | Neutral    | Bad         
> E     | Good       | Good        
> F     | Bad        | Bad         
> G     | Neutral    | Neutral     
> H     | Error      | Error       
> I     | Good       | Error       
> I     | Bad        | Error       
> I     | Neutral    | Error       
> I     | Error      | Error       
> J     | Good       | Error       
> J     | Bad        | Error       
> J     | Error      | Error       
> K     | Good       | Error       
> K     | Neutral    | Error       
> K     | Error      | Error       
> L     | Bad        | Error       
> L     | Neutral    | Error       
> L     | Error      | Error       
> M     | Good       | Error       
> M     | Error      | Error       
> N     | Bad        | Error       
> N     | Error      | Error       
> O     | Neutral    | Error       
> O     | Error      | Error
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas
I didnt explain my question the best but get the results i was after using you first mehod. I think it I have covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a priority such as:

1. Error
2. Neutral
3. Bad
4. Good

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when row_status = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by group) > 0
             then 'Error'
             when sum(case when row_status = 'Neutral' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by group) > 0
             then 'Neutral'
             when sum(case when row_status = 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by group) > 0
             then 'Bad'
             else 'Good'
        end) as group_status             
from t;
```

EDIT:

I think your revised logic is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(row_status) over (partition by group) = max(row_status) over (partition by group)
             then min(row_status) over (partition by group)
             when sum(case when row_status = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by group) > 0
             then 'Error'
             else 'Bad'
        end) as group_status             
from t;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff
I didnt explain the rules very good with my original question but have updated my question

Comment: Not having any luck with your sql https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=225a3a6d9de49b1a69470953824d9844

Comment: @TBP . . . The SQL Fiddle really helps.  I fixed the query.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff are you able to fix the query again on dbfiddle.uk and send me the updated url? forpas method works for me but would like to see your method as well.